# Threads Not Running In Parallel

Tags: multithreading, rust

I'm trying to follow the official documentation to get a grasp of the sense of the language.  However, I come across the issue that threads are not being run in parallel in [this tutorial](http://doc.rust-lang.org/book/dining-philosophers.html).

I tried to make the issue more obvious by introducing some changes in the code, but nothing has changed.  Here is the source:

`src/main.rs`:

```rust
extern crate rand;

use rand::Rng;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;

struct Philosopher {
    name: String,
    left: usize,
    right: usize,
}

struct Table {
    forks: Vec<Mutex<()>>,
}

impl Philosopher {
    fn new(name: &str, left: usize, right: usize) -> Philosopher {
        Philosopher {
            name: name.to_string(),
            left: left,
            right: right,
        }
    }

    fn eat(&self, table: &Table) {
        let _left = table.forks[self.left].lock().unwrap();
        let _right = table.forks[self.right].lock().unwrap();
        let sleeptime = rand::thread_rng().gen_range(1, 1001);

        println!("{} is eating for {} milliseconds.", self.name, sleeptime);
        thread::sleep_ms(sleeptime);
        println!("{} is done eating.", self.name);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let table = Arc::new(Table {
        forks: vec![
            Mutex::new(()),
            Mutex::new(()),
            Mutex::new(()),
            Mutex::new(()),
            Mutex::new(()),
        ],
    });
    let philosophers = vec![
        Philosopher::new("Baruch Spinoza", 0, 1),
        Philosopher::new("Gilles Deleuze", 1, 2),
        Philosopher::new("Karl Marx", 2, 3),
        Philosopher::new("Friedrich Nietzsche", 3, 4),
        Philosopher::new("Michel Foucault", 0, 4),
    ];

    let handles: Vec<_> = philosophers.into_iter().map(|p| {
        let table = table.clone();
        thread::spawn(move || p.eat(&table))
    }).collect();

    for h in handles {
        h.join().unwrap();
    }
}
```

`Cargo.toml`:

```toml
[package]
name = "philosophers"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["shinkou <someone@somewhere.com>"]

[dependencies]
rand = "0.3.0"
```

I'm not sure if my setup is the cause, but I'm testing it on a VM (Ubuntu 14.10) under Win7.

I ran the code a numerous (20+) times. Without a single exception, the order was always

```
Michel Foucault is eating for 214 milliseconds.
Michel Foucault is done eating.
Friedrich Nietzsche is eating for 34 milliseconds.
Friedrich Nietzsche is done eating.
Karl Marx is eating for 167 milliseconds.
Karl Marx is done eating.
Gilles Deleuze is eating for 813 milliseconds.
Gilles Deleuze is done eating.
Baruch Spinoza is eating for 207 milliseconds.
Baruch Spinoza is done eating.
```

However, when I got home and ran it on my Slackware64 (14.1) box, the order changes randomly.

EDIT: added code to print out the random eating time

Comment: @Shepmaster It reminds me of some of the unusual styles used by particular schools of JavaScript development. Stacked commas look really odd without `var` there to align things.

Comment: When I run this code, I see multiple philosophers eating concurrently: `Baruch Spinoza is eating. Karl Marx is eating. Baruch Spinoza is done eating. Michel Foucault is eating.`

Comment: @Shepmaster personally, I find that unreadable (too sparse), but I guess it's good Rust does not enforce a single style opinion :)

Comment: we have rustfmt for enforcing the Rust-style ;)

Comment: I love curly brackets style though - in separate lines :) I'm using this style too

Comment: @evilone I'm glad to see someone with similar coding style.  That said, I wonder why people like to enforce others' coding style when they are perfectly clear and readable, while they talk about freedom blah blah on the other hand.

Comment: @shinkou Usually different languages have developed their own style. So it'll be nice to follow code formatting style of the language that you write :)

Comment: @shinkou: your code was deviating substantially from the established standard style and was substantially impairing readadbility for the sorts of people that will be referring to this question. Some styles are clear enough that I’ll leave them as they are, others are different enough—harmfully so, in my opinion—that I will normalise them for ease of reference. Stack Overflow is not about you, it’s about the question, and if changing the formatting makes the problem easier to understand or answer, *it should be changed*. Accepted conventions *should* be followed in such places.

Comment: @Shepmaster I've updated the post as you have requested.

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Impairing readability?  That's the first time I've ever heard that.  Interesting.  Every time when people complained about my coding style, it was because of the format being overly clear which takes them more time to type if they follow the style.  lol  Anyway, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Philosophers [eat randomly](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=9093b85a75f924c60ed2f6e366aea72a) with the modern version of rustc and the 2015 edition. I'll add a delay between taking a left and a right fork to replicate the original issue.

```
    let _left = table.forks[self.left].lock().unwrap();
+   thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(150));
    let _right = table.forks[self.right].lock().unwrap();
```

No matter how many times you run [the program](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=release&edition=2015&gist=ab2f68ccafd19ed548b3f4f692937757), it prints the following output:

```
Friedrich Nietzsche is eating for 666 milliseconds.
Friedrich Nietzsche is done eating.
Karl Marx is eating for 691 milliseconds.
Karl Marx is done eating.
Gilles Deleuze is eating for 553 milliseconds.
Gilles Deleuze is done eating.
Baruch Spinoza is eating for 22 milliseconds.
Baruch Spinoza is done eating.
Michel Foucault is eating for 911 milliseconds.
Michel Foucault is done eating.
```

I can't give a solid answer to why it happens. It seems like it depends on the OS thread handling mechanism. Though to solve it, you can add a delay after releasing the locks:

```rust
thread::spawn(move || {
    p.eat(&table);
+   thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(150));
})
```